# QGIS 3.28.7 Split merged line network to surveyed lines network

Tags: shapefile, buffer, merge, splitting, select-by-location

I need to create a shapefile of unsurvey[image] road section in the network. I am using a surveyed layer (Lines) that does not overlap on the network. It is just parallel. I tried the select by location using a buffer for the surveyed road. And selected the "are within" option and switched the selection in the attribute table. From there, I noticed some selected lines inside the buffer. They shouldn't be highlighted. I tried to merge the sections of the road network to get one record representing the entire network. Then using the "split with lines" option. Input is the network, split layer is the Surveyed roads layer. I also tried the saga option call "Split lines with lines". As a result, the merged network layer isn't split reflecting the surveyed layer sections. Is there an option in QGIS that I can use to split the merge network. So the cuts are the same than the surveyed layer.

Comment: Solved my own issue. I used the difference tool under Vector, Geoprocessing tools.